# Replace the loading icon

Tags: feature-request, design, icon

I believe we should replace the Loading Icon with the default pin wheel found in Ubuntu - something like this

[image: Ubuntu Throbber]

As opposed to the default stackoverflow icon.

Comment: Just thought I'd add this often knows as a "throbber" :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can do that. I'm all for keeping the Ubuntu theme consistent. I'll add this to my queue of things to fix!

Answer (score 1):

This site uses the same code as all of the other StackExchange sites... I don't think they want to deviate from the main codebase too much.

Comment: I understand that - but at the same time http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/ mentions requests to change specific sites. It's a super small thing and will likely be something to consider for styling - Just thought I would suggest something different

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple as changing a style sheet? Isn't that already done for each site?